# Ammeter changes the behaviour of my circuit – how?

Tags: current-measurement, troubleshooting

Calling it a circuit is perhaps overstating it, as it's essentially three black boxes: a [Dell MK394 external power supply](https://www.tec-int.com/dell-mk394.html) originally for a desktop PC, a [DT9205A multimeter,](https://ftaelectronics.com/professional-digital-multitester-ammeter-voltmeter-multimeter-dt9205a.html) and a [Yaesu FT-450D](https://www.yaesu.com/indexVS.cfm?cmd=DisplayProducts&ProdCatID=102&encProdID=870B3CA7CFCB61E6A599B0EFEA2217E4) HF transceiver. The power supply is quite straightforward: it outputs +12V on a bunch of pins, 0V on another bunch, has a sense pin which powers the thing on when grounded and some other pin of unknown purpose but which doesn't seem to be important.

I was hoping to use the power supply for my transceiver, but it keeps tripping the overdraw protection when the radio powers on. When troubleshooting, I connected my multimeter in series, expecting to see a brief spike in current before the protection circuit kicked in.

Instead, the transceiver now reliably powers on and works just fine, with the amperage showing about what I'd expect when sending and receiving.

What exactly is going on here? I was under the impression that the shunt resistor in an ampere meter was practically insignificant, but here it's apparently enough to placate the protection circuit? Or could something else be going on here? Ideally I'd like to replicate it so I can complete my project.

Comment: "practically insignificant" is a relative thing. If you had 10mOhms of resistance to limit the capacitive inrush before, a 100mOhm shunt resistance is going to decrease inrush current whatever you had before by ten times.

Comment: Adding to what @DKNguyen - normal DVMs and especially their leads can add a surprising amount of resistance.

Comment: I think the reason why the power supply hits a current limit and shuts down, is that it's a 15A power supply, and the radio needs a 22A power supply. The meter in between adds some resistance so the current will be limited enough.

Comment: What's the resistance of your meter leads when touched together on minimum ohms range?

Comment: @Justme The power supply is actually 18A according to the specs on the supply itself, and the radio only draws 22A peak when transmitting. When receiving, it draws roughly an amp.

Comment: In addition to the finite series resistance (DC) of your multi-meter, it adds a small inductive reactance (AC) in series with the power supply.  The inductive reactance will reduce the turn-on (surge) current through the power supply when your transceiver turns on.  The total added series resistance seems to be enough to keep the power supply's overcurrent protection from triggering.